# how to use NOW or TODAY, but freeze the cell with its value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

if i use NOW or TODAY in a cell, it updates every time you press F9. What I want is a function that returns today's date but that is not dynamic, meaning that it freezes the date as of today. i cant have it update the date everytime i open the workbook.

thanks

Comment: i created a macro to do it but would prefer it to be a function. is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than entering `=TODAY()` in a cell, click on the cell and use this keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **;**

From Microsoft's [Excel shortcut and function keys](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-shortcut-and-function-keys-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f):

```
CTRL+;           Enters the current date.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that would be to just type in the date so today would be (for me) 12/18 and now would be 18/12/15 3:23, I would set the format correctly so that it displayed properly.

I researched this same problem but with =Rand(), I wanted to generate a quiz but every time the user entered an answer, the values refreshed and they automatically got it wrong.